# Sending 2 emails with PHP mailer fails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am rather puzzled with this one.

```
//SMTP servers details
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = "mail.hostserver.com";  
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;     
$mail->Username = $myEmail;  // SMTP usr
$mail->Password = "****";    // SMTP pass
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;   
$mail->From = $patrickEmail; 
$mail->FromName = "***";    
$mail->AddAddress($email, $firstName . " " . $lastName); 
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = $client_subject;
$mail->Body    = $client_msg;

if($mail->Send())
{

$mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();
...
$mail->From = "DO_NOT_REPLY@..."; 
$mail->FromName = "****";    
$mail->AddAddress($ToEmail1, "***"); //To: (recipients).
$mail->AddAddress($ToEmail2, "***"); //To: (recipients).
$mail->WordWrap = 50;            
$mail->IsHTML(true);             
$mail->Subject = $notification_subject;
$mail->Body    = $notification_msg;
if($mail->Send())
{
...
```

The first email sends fine. The second one doesn't. What could be the reason for that behavior? Am I missing some kind of reset?

---

Update: using a different mail server seems to work so apparently it's a setting of that specific mail server causing problems. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Remove `$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();` and give it a try  ....

Comment: @Baba Thanks but no dice. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: I dont recommend using PHPMailer. Writing your own simple mail class will be a much more hands-on experience with less bugs. I dumped the phpmailer class because it ships with a ton of bugs and very silly mistakes...

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Can you give examples of bugs and silly mistakes?

Answer (score 9):

Some providers impose restrictions on the number of messages that can be sent within a specific time span. To determine if your problem depends by a provider "rate limit", you should try to add a pause after the first send. For example:

```
if ($mail->Send()) {
    sleep(10);  // Seconds
    ...
    if ($mail->Send()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, by progressively lowering the sleep time, you should be able to determine which is the rate limit.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it's worth a try. I will have a go this week-end.

Comment: If the execution time setting of your php set up is the default (30 seconds), this will stop executing when that timer runs out.

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell You're right; thank you for making it clear. Now I've edited my answer to reduce the sleep time from 30 to 10 seconds.

Comment: this resolve the issue for me :  I needed to send a confirmation to treatement + bill in a an another mail, both in option in my back-office, thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Try this:
As @Felipe Alameda A mentioned `Remove $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;`

```
// for every mail
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'There was a problem sending this mail!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Mail sent!';        
}
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you need to create new PHPMailer object for every sent email. If you want to share some common setup, use something like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
/* Configure common settings */

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $mail2 = clone $mail;
    $mail2->MsgHTML("Dear ".$row["fname"].",<br>".$cbody);
    $mail2->AddAddress($row["email"], $row["fname"]);
    $mail2->send();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is `$mail->SMTPAuth = false;`

It is hard to believe there are ISP or SMTP providers that don't require authentication, even if they are free.

You may try this to check for errors instead of or in addition to checking for `send()` true:

```
  if ( $mail->IsError() ) { // 
    echo ERROR;
  }
  else {
    echo NO ERRORS;
  }

 //Try adding this too, for debugging:
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  // enables SMTP debug information
```

Everything else in your code looks fine. We use PHPMailer a lot and never had any problems with it

Comment: It was set to true originally. I changed it to false to try, and forgot to set it back (both work for the first email, not for the second.

Comment: Remove `$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; ` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The key *may* lie in the parts you have omitted. Is the domain of the sender of both emails the same? Otherwise the SMTP host may see this as a relay attempt. If you have access to the SMTP server logs, check these; they might offer a clue.

Also, check what `$mail->ErrorInfo` says... it might tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Yup, same domain sender. I don't have access to the SMTP logs. For $mail->ErrorInfo, I would need to modify my script (it's called through Ajax)

Answer (score 1):

i personally would try to make small steps like sending same email.. so just clear recipients and try to send identical email (this code works for me). If this code passes you can continue to adding back your previous lines and debug where it fails

and maybe `$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();` doing problems

```
//SMTP servers details
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = "mail.hostserver.com";  
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;     
$mail->Username = $myEmail;  // SMTP usr
$mail->Password = "****";    // SMTP pass
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;   
$mail->From = $patrickEmail; 
$mail->FromName = "***";    
$mail->AddAddress($email, $firstName . " " . $lastName); 
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = $client_subject;
$mail->Body    = $client_msg;
// all above is copied
if($mail->Send()) {
  sleep(5);
  $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
  $mail->AddAddress('another@email.com'); //some another email

}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got organizational problems here.

I recommend:

1. Set your settings (SMTP, user, pass)
2. Create new email object with info from an array holding messages and to addresses
3. Send email
4. Goto step 2

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following example.,

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address1 = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$address2 = "whoto@otherdomain.com";

$mail->AddAddress($address1, "John Doe");
$mail->AddAddress($address2, "John Peter");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment if any
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment if any

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

**Note :** Better you can make a multiple user email and name as an ARRAY, like

```
<?php

    $recipients = array(
       'person1@domain.com' => 'Person One',
       'person2@domain.com' => 'Person Two',
       // ..
    );

    foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
    {
       $mail->AddCC($email, $name);
    }

    (or)

    foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
    {
       $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
    }
?>
```

i think this may help you to resolve your problem.