# PHP mailer not validating after sending a second email

Tags: php, validation, email, phpmailer

This is an updated msg's with a working code for sending two different emails using php mailer. It also has working validation server site.

You need to create you own mail class or use the normal one.

Hope someone else can use it two!

Thank you!!

```
<?php

require"validation.php";

  ob_start();

  $name      = trim($_POST['name']);
  $email     = $_POST['email'];
  $comments  = $_POST['comments'];
  $info_email= 'example@example.com';
  $info_name = 'Example';


require"PHPMailer/mail.inc.php";

$cams="$name has just made a comment or posted a question";
$camb= "<html> 

<head>
<h3> $name has  asked the following question or comment on you website:</h3>
</head>
<body>

$comments <br><br><br>

Their information: <br><br>

<table cellspacing=\"4\" cellpadding=\"4\" border=\"1\">

 <tr>
  <td align=\"center\">Name:</td>
  <td align=\"center\"> $name</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td align=\"center\">Email:</td>
  <td align=\"center\"> $email</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<img src=\"cid:mailhead\" alt=\"shop logo used in emails\"  />

Pleasy try to reply as soon as possible.<br>
Thank you!!

</body>
</html>";

$mail = new MailCon;
$mail->IsSMTP();     
$mail->isHTML(true); 

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress($info_email, $info_name);

$mail->Subject = $cams;
$mail->MsgHTML($camb);

if ($mail->Send()) {

$mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
  $mail->ClearReplyTos();
  $mail->ClearCustomHeaders();

  $cums = 'Thank you for using our contact form.';


  $message = file_get_contents('mail/example.html'); 
    $message = str_replace('%username%', $name, $message); 
    $message = str_replace('%email%', $email, $message); 
    $message = str_replace('%comments%', $comments, $message); 

$alt_body="Thank you for asking us a question or making a comment. We will reply as soon as possible.";

  $mail = new MailCon;
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->IsHTML(true);      

  $mail->From = $info_email;
  $mail->FromName = $info_name;
  $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);  // Add a recipient 



  $mail->Subject = $cums;
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);
  $mail->AltBody = $alt_body;
  $mail->Send(); 

}

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

This is the validation bit wich you can include using require once.

```
 <?php

 $name      = trim($_POST['name']);
  $email     = $_POST['email'];
  $comments  = $_POST['comments'];

  if (strlen($name) < 2) {
$error['name'] = "Please enter your name";  
  }

  if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is',     $email)) {
$error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address"; 
  }

  if (strlen($comments) < 3) {
$error['comments'] = "Please leave a comment.";
  }

  if (!$error) {

 echo "<div class='alert-box success'>Thanks " . $name . ". Your message has        been sent.<a href='' class='close' onclick='clearForms()'>&times;</a></div>";

  } # end if no error
  else {

 $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['name'] . "</div> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['email'] . "</div> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['comments'] . "</div>" : null;

    echo $response;

  exit();

  } # end if there was an error sending

  ?>
```

Comment: What SMTP Server are you using? [See this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561235/sending-2-emails-with-php-mailer-fails?rq=1)

Comment: @ Brock Hensley, the mail itself works really well. It is the validating that is not working in the script. Your link is for when the second mail cannot be send. This is a php issue more then a smtp server issue (I think).

Comment: For your 2nd `$mail` try using a different variable name?

Comment: @BrockHensley-FKAdirt I tried that but with no result. I also including my connection info to my main script but with no luck. Might have to go javascript here, although I would have liked server side validation..

Comment: So does the `!$mail->Send()` text get displayed but the emails work? Have you tried without the output buffering?

Comment: @ Brock Hensley, I got it to work! I updated my post! Thank you very much for the tips!